# R: quadratic term in a beta regression

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, quadratic-form, beta-regression

My hypothesis is that along a gradient of habitat structural complexity *'a'*, the fish diversity *'y'* increases until an optimum level but decreases after that (which kinda I have noticed in the graphic inspection). Then, I am really interested in this hump-shaped relationship.

Using a beta regression, I want to regress *y* against two predictor variables (*a* and *b*).

```
betareg(y ~ a + b)
```

However, visual inspection of the data showed that *y* seems to respond to the predictor *a* with a quadratic trend. So, I had included a second-order term, like this:

```
betareg(y ~ I(a^2) + b)
```

I have two questions:

1) Is the R syntax correct?

2) To find what model (with or without the quadratic term) fits better, can I use the Akaike Information Criterion? or is there another way?

Comment: Generally speaking, you should include the linear term in the model if you are going to include an interaction.  The syntax looks fine to me, something like `y ~ poly(a,2) + b` should work too. So far as model fit, AIC is one criterion you can use for model fit, but I would say that it depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. If I don't intend to include an interaction, do I need to consider the linear term?

Comment: If you don't include the interaction, then the choice of which variables to include depends deeply on what you want to achieve.  Can you tells us more about your problem so we can be more helpful?

Comment: My hypothesis is that along a gradient of habitat structural complexity, the fish diversity increases until an optimum level but decreases after that (which kinda I have noticed in the graphic inspection). So, from the beginning, I am really interested in this hump-shaped relationship.
If you need more information, let me know.

Comment: few of us are ecologists.  If you could please update your question with relevant plots and a laymen explanation of your problem, I think we would be better equipped to help.

Comment: In light of the update, I'm still confident my answer is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As mentioned in the comments, using the `I()` syntax will not include the linear term as well as the quadratic. You want to include the linear term for the quadratic to be meaningful. You can see how `m2a` below doesn't estimate the linear term, while `m2b` does.
2. The `{betareg}` documentation uses a likelihood ratio test to compare models. See the `lmtest::lrtest()` call below. You can use AIC if you prefer, too. See the final call below.
3. The question in the comments is if the lower-order polynomial has to be included (the linear term. The code in the original post does not do this, but the `poly` function does). The answer is yes, but I wanted to get a canonical reference:

> In order that the higher order tearms have meaning, all lower order terms must be included, since higher order terms are reflective of the specific level of curvature they represent only if all lower order terms are partialed out.

(p. 201 of Applied Multiple Regression/Correlation Analysis for the Behavioral Sciences, Third Edition, by Cohen, Cohen, West, & Aiken, 2003).

```
> library(betareg)
> data("GasolineYield", package = "betareg")
> m1 <- betareg(yield ~ batch + temp, data = GasolineYield)
> 
> m2a <- betareg(yield ~ batch + I(temp^2), data = GasolineYield)
> summary(m2a)$coef$mean
                 Estimate   Std. Error    z value      Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -4.406588e+00 1.527850e-01 -28.841762 6.427826e-183
batch1       1.727920e+00 1.223814e-01  14.119137  2.895143e-45
batch2       1.335722e+00 1.426937e-01   9.360758  7.916646e-21
batch3       1.569727e+00 1.405982e-01  11.164635  6.074007e-29
batch4       1.072718e+00 1.237826e-01   8.666140  4.470177e-18
batch5       1.179130e+00 1.252837e-01   9.411683  4.882550e-21
batch6       1.066340e+00 1.281983e-01   8.317892  8.954156e-17
batch7       5.423312e-01 1.317748e-01   4.115591  3.861880e-05
batch8       4.597893e-01 1.318104e-01   3.488263  4.861689e-04
batch9       3.741060e-01 1.433745e-01   2.609292  9.072968e-03
I(temp^2)    1.642624e-05 7.425293e-07  22.122009 1.940880e-108
> 
> m2b <- betareg(yield ~ batch + poly(temp, 2), data = GasolineYield)
> summary(m2b)$coef$mean
                 Estimate Std. Error     z value      Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    -2.5150922 0.08341531 -30.1514457 1.026828e-199
batch1          1.7239674 0.09981230  17.2720941  7.632203e-67
batch2          1.3134429 0.11667217  11.2575508  2.125849e-29
batch3          1.5670879 0.11473934  13.6578087  1.813596e-42
batch4          1.0539815 0.10112212  10.4228582  1.950032e-25
batch5          1.1186577 0.10329468  10.8297706  2.487777e-27
batch6          1.0310533 0.10501220   9.8184138  9.380791e-23
batch7          0.5425498 0.10758391   5.0430382  4.581977e-07
batch8          0.5058092 0.10794747   4.6856976  2.790080e-06
batch9          0.3892485 0.11688072   3.3303051  8.675086e-04
poly(temp, 2)1  4.2881801 0.16144971  26.5604702 1.944048e-155
poly(temp, 2)2 -0.1257151 0.13522198  -0.9296939  3.525296e-01
> 
> lmtest::lrtest(m2b, m1)
Likelihood ratio test

Model 1: yield ~ batch + poly(temp, 2)
Model 2: yield ~ batch + temp
  #Df LogLik Df  Chisq Pr(>Chisq)
1  13 85.221                     
2  12 84.798 -1 0.8466     0.3575
>
> c(linear = AIC(m1), quadratic = AIC(m2b))
   linear quadratic 
-145.5951 -144.4417
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The explanation was very clear. I will use the likelihood ratio test as you suggested.

If I have understood you correctly, is the option without estimate the linear term (m2a) always wrong? even if I don't intend to include this interaction?

Comment: In short, yes: think of it as a variable interacting with itself. Without the main effects in the model, you cannot meaningfully interpret the interaction. I can find a canonical reference at some point later today if nobody beats me to it first. It should be explained cogently in a classic text like Cohen Cohen Aiken and West, I would imagine

Comment: @BarbaraQuirino I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: I really appreciate your attention. Now I understand why I need to include the lower-order term. Also, thank you so much for the example and the reference.

Comment: No problem! If it answers it, feel free to mark that as answered. (Folks keep track of how often questions get marked as answered on each Stack Exchange community.)